# how to sort a list with different attributes in java

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I want sort a list of student object containing attributes name and course such that the sorting is done based on name and if two names are same then it should consider course for sorting... I can do it separately but want a single list... PLz help...

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package studentlist;

import java.util.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Administrator
 */
public class StudentList {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    String name, course;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCourse() {
        return course;
    }

    public void setCourse(String course) {
        this.course = course;
    }

    public StudentList(String name, String course) {
        this.name = name;
        this.course = course;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        List<StudentList> list = new ArrayList<StudentList>();

        list.add(new StudentList("Shaggy", "mca"));
        list.add(new StudentList("Roger", "mba"));
        list.add(new StudentList("Roger", "bba"));
        list.add(new StudentList("Tommy", "ca"));
        list.add(new StudentList("Tammy", "bca"));

        Collections.sort(list, new NameComparator());
        Iterator ir = list.iterator();

        while (ir.hasNext()) {
            StudentList s = (StudentList) ir.next();
            System.out.println(s.name + " " + s.course);
        }

        System.out.println("\n\n\n ");
        Collections.sort(list, new CourseComparator());
        Iterator ir1 = list.iterator();

        while (ir1.hasNext()) {
            StudentList s = (StudentList) ir1.next();
            System.out.println(s.name + " " + s.course);
        }

    }

}

class NameComparator implements Comparator<StudentList> {

    public int compare(StudentList s1, StudentList s2) {

        return s1.name.compareTo(s2.name);

    }

}

class CourseComparator implements Comparator<StudentList> {

    public int compare(StudentList s1, StudentList s2) {
        return s1.course.compareTo(s2.course);
    }
}
```

Comment: you already know the condition , now apply this in your comparator class

Answer (score 6):

You just have to put both the comparison in a single *Comparator*.

- First test the `name` are equal or not:

  - If they are not equal, then return the result of comparison of `name`.
  - If they are equal, move to compare the `courses`:

Following comparator would work:

```
class NameCourseComparator implements Comparator<StudentList> {

    public int compare(StudentList s1, StudentList s2) {
        if (s1.name.equals(s2.name)) {
            return s1.course.compareTo(s2.course);
        }
        return s1.name.compareTo(s2.name);
    }
}
```

Comment: its giving the output as: Roger bba
Tommy bca
Tommy ca
Roger mba
Shaggy mca  i want it as :  Roger bba  Roger mba
Tommy bca
Tommy ca
Shaggy mca

Comment: @TanujJeena How are you using it? It's working fine in my case. Are you still sorting it twice? You just need one sort now, with `new NameCourseComparator()`.

Answer (score 3):

One simple way:

Sort the list according to the name first. After that loop through the list again. If you find any same name in order, then compare the course and update the list accordingly.

Comment: this is basically doing a sort twice, which isn't necessary

Comment: @Mateusz yes it is. I just suggesting a simple way which I thought of when I answered the question. Though it is inefficient, but still it answer the question correctly :)

Answer (score 0):

You could just tweak the `NameComparator` a bit

```
class NameComparator implements Comparator<StudentList> {
      public int compare(StudentList s1, StudentList s2) {
        if(s1.getName().equals(s2.getName()) {
           return s1.getCourse().compareToIgnoreCase(s2.getCourse());
        }else {
           return s1.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(s2.getName());   
      }
}
```

Comment: you should use equals to compare string

Comment: @upog: Thanks for the correction. I've updated my answer accordingly.